# How to add dynamic file to docker container

Tags: docker

whenever I run a docker container, I want to send dynamic filename as some environment variable.

That is accessible in container so its printing its value when we 'echo'.

But ADD command not adding that file.

Dockerfile:

```
ADD $filename ./
echo ls # Not showing file
```

docker run -e filename='/path/to/file.extension'

Answer (score 3):

Try using a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) instead:

```
$ echo "hello world" > somefile.txt
$ docker run -it --rm -v $PWD/somefile.txt:/data/somefile.txt alpine cat /data/somefile.txt
hello world
```

The Dockerfile lists the actions that occur when you run a "docker build". It's not possible to pass in an environment variable at run-time, because, at that point, the image is already built :-)

Comment: The volume approach is a good idea, thank you. Note, you can set environment variables for your containers at runtime via the `docker run --env` and `docker run --env-file` commands.  Useful technique -- especially helps to keep env-local settings and passwords / other secrets out of Docker images.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson I agree completely, and using environment variables is recommended by the 12 Factor website (https://12factor.net/config). However in this case there was an attempt to use an environment variable within a Dockerfile, something can only be supported during a Docker build. Since this question was answered, Docker now supports build arguments, See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables-build-arg

Answer (score 1):

`ADD` is run during compile (build) time. When you run `docker exec -e` that is after the container has been built.

You cannot add dynamic files because it's compiled. The previous command about volumes is correct because you can provide those files ad-hoc during `exec` and have your application pick them up.

Answer (score 1):

to add to Mark's answer.

If you want to use a [docker-compose.yml](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) file (a good idea if youre planning on running the container over and over).

```
mysql:
  image: mysql
  volumes:
    - /someLocalFolder/lib/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql
```

you can add as many volumes as you like this way, including individual files which can be handy for config etc.